# Chatterbot failing to install

Tags: python, pip, installation, chatterbot

I´ve been trying to install ChatterBot, its a new machine so its pretty much a fresh installation of python, i'am running python 3.8 64bits

Complete log

```
C:\Users\Marcos>pip install chatterbot
Collecting chatterbot
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6c/0e/dac0d82f34f86bf509cf5ef3e2dfc5aa7d444bd843a2330ceb7d854f84f2/ChatterBot-1.0.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pint>=0.8.1
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/90/f9/2bdadf95328c02e57a79e5370d1e911a9c6fdb9952b6c4de44d6c7052978/Pint-0.10.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting sqlalchemy<1.3,>=1.2
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f9/67/d07cf7ac7e6dd0bc55ba62816753f86d7c558107104ca915e730c9ec2512/SQLAlchemy-1.2.19.tar.gz (5.7MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 5.7MB 6.8MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in c:\users\marcos\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from chatterbot) (2019.3)
Collecting mathparse<0.2,>=0.1
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c3/e5/4910fb85950cb960fcf3f5aabe1c8e55f5c9201788a1c1302b570a7e1f84/mathparse-0.1.2-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting nltk<4.0,>=3.2
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f6/1d/d925cfb4f324ede997f6d47bea4d9babba51b49e87a767c170b77005889d/nltk-3.4.5.zip
Collecting python-dateutil<2.8,>=2.7
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/74/68/d87d9b36af36f44254a8d512cbfc48369103a3b9e474be9bdfe536abfc45/python_dateutil-2.7.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pymongo<4.0,>=3.3
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/77/5e/f30374f2a997710913c7616eb087e6473ccfd8a46eacee956d7fb8c7dd27/pymongo-3.10.1-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (355kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 358kB 6.4MB/s
Collecting pyyaml<5.2,>=5.1
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e3/e8/b3212641ee2718d556df0f23f78de8303f068fe29cdaa7a91018849582fe/PyYAML-5.1.2.tar.gz
Collecting spacy<2.2,>=2.1
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1f/e2/46650d03c7ff2b57ed7af211d41c3f606540f7adea92b5af65fcf9f605c0/spacy-2.1.9.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\marcos\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' 'c:\users\marcos\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-nntoyoz6\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools 'wheel>0.32.0,<0.33.0' Cython 'cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'preshed>=2.0.1,<2.1.0' 'murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0' 'thinc>=7.0.8,<7.1.0'
       cwd: None
  Complete output (62 lines):
  Collecting setuptools
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/af/e7/02db816dc88c598281bacebbb7ccf2c9f1a6164942e88f1a0fded8643659/setuptools-45.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting wheel<0.33.0,>0.32.0
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ff/47/1dfa4795e24fd6f93d5d58602dd716c3f101cfd5a77cd9acbe519b44a0a9/wheel-0.32.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting Cython
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/41/2c/9d873fc8d1be29af12a1d41707461399327396da10e50e183754aa4136b9/Cython-0.29.14-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
  Collecting cymem<2.1.0,>=2.0.2
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8c/1f/43be34e4decc602fae2bda73b05525bc49deff44baeb95611b23a2929195/cymem-2.0.3-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
  Collecting preshed<2.1.0,>=2.0.1
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0b/14/c9aa735cb9c131545fc9e23031baccb87041ac9215b3d75f99e3cf18f6a3/preshed-2.0.1.tar.gz
  Collecting murmurhash<1.1.0,>=0.28.0
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5b/73/129c1aed56c88a446c70e4eda186fe014bfb8330478e5e257cc923bd3e15/murmurhash-1.0.2-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
  Collecting thinc<7.1.0,>=7.0.8
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/92/39/ea2a3d5b87fd52fc865fd1ceb7b91dca1f85e227d53e7a086d260f6bcb93/thinc-7.0.8.tar.gz
  Collecting blis<0.3.0,>=0.2.1
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/59/9e/84a83616cbe5daa94909da38b780e93bf566dc2113c3dc35d7b4cad52f63/blis-0.2.4.tar.gz
  Collecting wasabi<1.1.0,>=0.0.9
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/21/e1/e4e7b754e6be3a79c400eb766fb34924a6d278c43bb828f94233e0124a21/wasabi-0.6.0-py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting srsly<1.1.0,>=0.0.6
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a1/bb/0982e39b1a6dd652d7605f199cc5209746145f3a9e677c0014302cc22f66/srsly-1.0.1-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
  Collecting numpy>=1.7.0
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/95/47/ea0ae5a778aae07ede486f3dc7cd4b788dc53e11b01a17251b020f76a01d/numpy-1.18.1-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
  Collecting plac<1.0.0,>=0.9.6
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9e/9b/62c60d2f5bc135d2aa1d8c8a86aaf84edb719a59c7f11a4316259e61a298/plac-0.9.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting tqdm<5.0.0,>=4.10.0
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/72/c9/7fc20feac72e79032a7c8138fd0d395dc6d8812b5b9edf53c3afd0b31017/tqdm-4.41.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Installing collected packages: setuptools, wheel, Cython, cymem, preshed, murmurhash, numpy, blis, wasabi, srsly, plac, tqdm, thinc
      Running setup.py install for preshed: started
      Running setup.py install for preshed: finished with status 'done'
      Running setup.py install for blis: started
      Running setup.py install for blis: finished with status 'error'
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: 'c:\users\marcos\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Marcos\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-dsthm_0n\\blis\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Marcos\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-dsthm_0n\\blis\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-md34dflk\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 'C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-nntoyoz6\overlay' --compile
           cwd: C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dsthm_0n\blis\
      Complete output (25 lines):
      BLIS_COMPILER? None
      running install
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis
      copying blis\about.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis
      copying blis\benchmark.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis
      copying blis\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis\tests
      copying blis\tests\common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis\tests
      copying blis\tests\test_dotv.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis\tests
      copying blis\tests\test_gemm.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis\tests
      copying blis\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis\tests
      copying blis\cy.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis
      copying blis\py.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis
      copying blis\cy.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis
      copying blis\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\blis
      running build_ext
      error: [WinError 2] O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado
      msvc
      py_compiler msvc
      {'LS_COLORS': 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:', 'HOSTTYPE': 'x86_64', 'LESSCLOSE': '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s', 'LANG': 'C.UTF-8', 'OLDPWD': '/home/matt/repos/flame-blis', 'VIRTUAL_ENV': '/home/matt/repos/cython-blis/env3.6', 'USER': 'matt', 'PWD': '/home/matt/repos/cython-blis', 'HOME': '/home/matt', 'NAME': 'LAPTOP-OMKOB3VM', 'XDG_DATA_DIRS': '/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop', 'SHELL': '/bin/bash', 'TERM': 'xterm-256color', 'SHLVL': '1', 'LOGNAME': 'matt', 'PATH': '/home/matt/repos/cython-blis/env3.6/bin:/tmp/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/Users/matt/Documents/cmder/vendor/conemu-maximus5/ConEmu/Scripts:/mnt/c/Users/matt/Documents/cmder/vendor/conemu-maximus5:/mnt/c/Users/matt/Documents/cmder/vendor/conemu-maximus5/ConEmu:/mnt/c/Python37/Scripts:/mnt/c/Python37:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/iCLS:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/iCLS:/mnt/c/Windows/System32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/WiFi/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Common Files/Intel/WirelessCommon:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/mnt/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Git/cmd:/mnt/c/Program Files/LLVM/bin:/mnt/c/Windows/System32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH:/mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs:/mnt/c/Users/matt/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Users/matt/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/mnt/c/Users/matt/AppData/Roaming/npm:/snap/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox', 'PS1': '(env3.6) \\[\\e]0;\\u@\\h: \\w\\a\\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\\[\\033[01;32m\\]\\u@\\h\\[\\033[00m\\]:\\[\\033[01;34m\\]\\w\\[\\033[00m\\]\\$ ', 'VAGRANT_HOME': '/home/matt/.vagrant.d/', 'LESSOPEN': '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s', '_': '/home/matt/repos/cython-blis/env3.6/bin/python'}
      clang -c C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dsthm_0n\blis\blis\_src\config\bulldozer\bli_cntx_init_bulldozer.c -o C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpweh55tja\bli_cntx_init_bulldozer.o -O2 -funroll-all-loops -std=c99 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L -DBLIS_VERSION_STRING="0.5.0-6" -DBLIS_IS_BUILDING_LIBRARY -Iinclude\windows-x86_64 -I.\frame\3\ -I.\frame\ind\ukernels\ -I.\frame\1m\ -I.\frame\1f\ -I.\frame\1\ -I.\frame\include -IC:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dsthm_0n\blis\blis\_src\include\windows-x86_64
      ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\marcos\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Marcos\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-dsthm_0n\\blis\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Marcos\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-dsthm_0n\\blis\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-md34dflk\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 'C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-nntoyoz6\overlay' --compile Check the logs for full command output.
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\marcos\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' 'c:\users\marcos\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-nntoyoz6\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools 'wheel>0.32.0,<0.33.0' Cython 'cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'preshed>=2.0.1,<2.1.0' 'murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0' 'thinc>=7.0.8,<7.1.0' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ChatterBot` indirectly required `blis==0.2.4` and the version [doesn't provide](https://pypi.org/project/blis/0.2.4/#files) precompiled wheels for Python 3.8. My advice is to downgrade to Python 3.7.

If you want to compile `blis` for Python 3.8 see the compilation instructions at https://github.com/explosion/cython-blis#installation:

> If you want to install from source and you're on Windows, you'll need to install LLVM.